Shopping cart in a telegram bot with WebApp
dear comrades. Now I’m writing my thesis, namely a telegram bot for product delivery in python with aiogram 3. To make the bot a little more unique, I decided to use the relatively new telegram feature with WebApp, that is, product catalogs look like full-fledged windows in a real application. I use html(css) and JavaScript to create directory windows. I have already implemented a window with products, regulating their quantity, and also through JS the information is successfully transmitted to the bot, that is, the bot immediately gives a list of selected products through the 'web_app' method.
However, I had difficulties creating a full-fledged cart so that the bot would remember all the selected products, so that new ones could be added to it, as well as empty the entire cart (it would be desirable that each product in the cart could be deleted separately). It is possible without a database, since this is purely a template in essence. So I really ask for help with the implementation of the basket, I’m very stuck at this point, what can I come up with? You can also see how everything works in the video attached below. Python script 'main' with method 'web_app', which returns a list of selected products:
@dp.message()
    async def web_app(callback_query):
    json_data = callback_query.web_app_data.data
    parsed_data = json.loads(json_data)
    message = ""
    for item in parsed_data['items']:
        product_name = item['name']
        price = item['price']
        message += f"Продукт: {product_name}\n"
        message += f"Стоимость: {price}\n\n"
 
        message += f"Общая стоимость: {parsed_data['totalPrice']}"
 
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, f"""
        {message}
    """)

JavaSctipt and HTML with all catalog functions:
let tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;
    tg.expand();
    tg.MainButton.textColor = '#FFFFFF';
    tg.MainButton.color = '#2cab37';
    let items = {
    item1: { id: "item1", price: 80, quantity: 0, name: "Молоко коровка из кореновки 2,5%" },
    item2: { id: "item2", price: 120, quantity: 0, name: "Масло сливочное кубанский молочник 82,5%" },
    item3: { id: "item3", price: 70, quantity: 0, name: "Творог коровка из кореновки 9%" },
    item4: { id: "item4", price: 47, quantity: 0, name: "Пломбир коровка из кореновки" },
    item5: { id: "item5", price: 100, quantity: 0, name: "Кефир коровка из кореновки 2,5%" },
    item6: { id: "item6", price: 150, quantity: 0, name: "Ряженка коровка из кореновки 2,5%" },
    item7: { id: "item7", price: 110, quantity: 0, name: "Йогурт коровка из кореновки" },
    item8: { id: "item8", price: 70, quantity: 0, name: "Сгущенка коровка из кореновки 8,5%" }
    };
 
    function updateQuantity(itemId, change) {
    let item = items[itemId];
    item.quantity += change;
    if (item.quantity < 0) item.quantity = 0;
    if (item.quantity > 10) item.quantity = 10;
    document.getElementById("qty" + itemId.slice(-1)).innerText = item.quantity;
    toggleItem(itemId);
    }
 
    function toggleItem(itemId) {
    let item = items[itemId];
    let btn = document.getElementById("add" + itemId.slice(-1));
    let subtractBtn = document.getElementById("subtract" + itemId.slice(-1));
 
    btn.classList.remove('added-to-cart');
    btn.style.display = 'inline-block';
    subtractBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
 
    let totalPrice = calculateTotalPrice();
    if (totalPrice > 0) {
        tg.MainButton.setText(`Общая цена товаров: ${totalPrice}`);
        if (!tg.MainButton.isVisible) {
            tg.MainButton.show();
        }
    } else {
        tg.MainButton.hide();
    }
    }
 
    function openModal(element) {
            var productName = element.parentNode.querySelector('p').textContent;
            document.getElementById('product-name').textContent = productName;
            document.getElementById('my-modal').style.display = 'block';
        }
        function closeModal() {
    document.getElementById('my-modal').style.display = 'none';
    }
 
    document.getElementById("open-modal-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("my-modal").classList.add("open")
    })
 
    document.getElementById("close-my-modal-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("my-modal").classList.remove("open")
    })
    Telegram.WebApp.onEvent("mainButtonClicked", function() {
    let data = {
        items: Object.values(items).filter(item => item.quantity > 0),
        totalPrice: calculateTotalPrice()
    };
    tg.sendData(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
 
    function calculateTotalPrice() {
    return Object.values(items).reduce((total, item) => total + (item.price * 
    item.quantity), 0);
    }
 
    document.getElementById("add1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    updateQuantity("item1", 1);
    });
 
    document.getElementById("subtract1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    updateQuantity("item1", -1);
    });

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Молочные продукты</h1>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="item" id="item1">
                    <img src="image/11.png" alt="" class="img" id="open-modal-btn" onclick="openModal(this)">
                    <p>Молоко коровка из кореновки 2,5%</p>
                    <p>80 ₽</p>
                    <div class="btn-container">
                        <button class="btn" id="add1">+</button>
                        <span id="qty1">0</span>
                        <button class="btn" id="subtract1">-</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal" id="my-modal">
                    <div class="modal_box">
                        <button class="modal_close-btn" id="close-my-modal-btn" onclick="closeModal()">
                            <svg width="23" height="25" viewBox="0 0 23 25" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M2.09082 0.03125L22.9999 22.0294L20.909 24.2292L-8.73579e-05 2.23106L2.09082 0.03125Z" fill="#333333"/>
                                <path d="M0 22.0295L20.9091 0.0314368L23 2.23125L2.09091 24.2294L0 22.0295Z" fill="#333333"/>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                        <img src="image/11.png" alt="" class="img">
                        <h2>Молоко коровка из кореновки 2,5%</h2>

                        <p class="left"><span class="grey">Состав</span><br>
                            Цельное молоко, обезжиренное молоко<br>
                            <span class="grey">Количество</span><br>
                            900 мл<br>
                            <span class="grey">Цена</span><br>
                            80 ₽<br>
                            <span class="grey">Пищевая ценность на 100 г</span><br>
                            Белки: 3.0 г Жиры: 2,5 г Углеводы: 4,7 Калории: 55.0 ккал<br>
                            <span class="grey">Срок годности</span><br>
                            9 суток при температуре (4±2)°C
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

How the bot works:
text
I tried to create separate functions, ChatGPT just can't work with this bot.

It is possible without a database how would the bot know what you have in your cart otherwise? (Note that even a txt file called username_cart.txt counts as a database) (even a telegram message that you updated and modify with the cart contents)

Can you narrow-down the problem? What is your immediate blocker at this point, the concrete obstacle that you need help to resolve?

I rather mean that I don't want to use SQL here, let's do it all through a dictionary. But it's better to forget this topic. I created another one for this problem, but there I already have specific problems with the implementation and an incomprehensible error. I will be very grateful if you help
